scipy.integrate.quad gives incorrect value
I was trying defining a trajectory using velocity and curvature by time; i.e. v(t) and k(t).
To get x and y position at time t, I used scipy.integrate.quad but it gives a wrong value.
Below is what I've tried.
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import quad

# Define v(t) and k(t)
def v(t):
    return 10.0

def k(t):
    return 0.0

def dtheta(t):  # heading rate.
    return v(t) * k(t);

# Compute theta(t) by integrating dtheta
def theta(t):
    result, _ = quad(dtheta, 0, t, epsabs=1e-4, limit=100) # initial heading 0
    print(f"heading {result}")
    return result
    # return 0

# Define the integrands for x(t) and y(t)
def dx(t):
    ret = v(t) * np.cos(theta(t))
    print(f"dx {ret}")
    return ret

def dy(t):
    return v(t) * np.sin(theta(t))

# Integrate to find x(t) and y(t)
def x(t):
    result, _ = quad(dx, 0, t, epsabs=1e-4, limit=100) # initial x 0
    return result

def y(t):
    result, _ = quad(dy, 0, t, epsabs=1e-4, limit=100) # initial y 0
    return result

print(x(0.5))

As you can see, to test the code, I just put really simple values; constant 10 to velocity and constant 0 to curvature. Therefore, the heading should be constantly 0 and the expected x(0.5) is 5.0. However, it gives a strange number 4.235577740302726e-06. I checked that theta(t) always outputs 0 and dx(t) always outputs 10.0,
heading 0.0
dx 10.0
heading 0.0
dx 10.0
heading 0.0
dx 10.0
heading 0.0
dx 10.0
heading 0.0
dx 10.0
heading 0.0
dx 10.0
heading 0.0
dx 10.0
heading 0.0
dx 10.0
heading 0.0
dx 10.0
heading 0.0
dx 10.0
heading 0.0
dx 10.0
heading 0.0
dx 10.0
heading 0.0
dx 10.0
heading 0.0
dx 10.0
heading 0.0
dx 10.0
4.235577740302726e-06

It gives me a correct value (i.e. 5.0) if I manually return 0 for theta(t) but I don't like to do this cause it harms its applicability. What am I doing wrong here?

You can use solve_ivp(), which is designed for solving initial value problems for ODEs:
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp


def system(t, y, v, k):
    x, y_pos, theta = y
    dxdt = v(t) * np.cos(theta)
    dydt = v(t) * np.sin(theta)
    dthetadt = v(t) * k(t)
    return [dxdt, dydt, dthetadt]


def v(t):
    return 10.0 * np.exp(-t)


def k(t):
    return 0.1 * np.sin(2 * np.pi * t)


ts, te = (0, 0.5), np.linspace(0, 0.5, 100)
IVP = solve_ivp(lambda t, y: system(t, y, v, k), ts, [0, 0, 0], t_eval=te)

x1, y1 = IVP.y[0, -1], IVP.y[1, -1]
print(f"x(0.5) = {x1}, y(0.5) = {y1}")


Prints
x(0.5) = 3.89226601538334, y(0.5) = 0.4613683813905819



Great! Thank you for suggestion. Just curiosity, would you have any idea on why the above (i.e. using quad) did not work?

@HarveyKim quad can also work, if set properly. But, in the question, quad is being used to integrate dx and dy, but again inside the dx and dy, it is being called for theta. The nested integration leads to inaccurate and inefficient computation.
